# electronic music-incountable nouns vs uncountable nouns with adjectives

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I know that "music" is an uncountable noun, but can I write:

My favourite music is an electronic music.

Can I pyt "an" before music in this sentence and why?

Comment: I have certainly never seen it. And I'm not sure why *my favourite music is electronic music* would not suffice. I can however, conceive of a remark such as *Indian music, which employs half-tones, is an altogether different music to western music*.

Comment: @WS2: I don't find it impossible to imagine a competent native speaker coming out with OP's example. But it is very unusual phrasing, which is one of the reasons I think it's not at all a good idea for non-native speakers to use ELU in this way. They'll only end up more confused than ever, when all they really wanted to know is what forms native speakers *normally* use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.

Answer (score 2):

See [this article](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm).

> We do not usually use the indefinite article a/an with uncountable nouns. We cannot say "an information" or "a music".

Normally one would say "a piece of electronic music", generically called "a 'something' of" in the above article.  For instance, "an example of jazz music" and "a classic of contemporary music", each give a different noun to pair with the indefinite article.